# Some Areas 51 sites skipped Private Beta stage?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase, private-beta

Whilst browsing Area 51 Proposal sites, I found four examples where there is no "Private Beta Start Date" mentioned:

1. [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)
2. [Mi Yodeya](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/mi-yodeya)
3. [SharePoint](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint)
4. [Electrical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electrical-engineering)

Am I safe to conclude they did not have a private beta stage or is it simply a bug? In the event there was no private beta stage, any idea(s) as to why this would have occurred?

Comment: The notices in 3 and 4 are pretty self-explanatory: these sites did not arise through Area 51 but were imported. I think the same applies to 1, but the notice has been replaced with the closure notice. Don't know about 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi Yodeya is actually a migration of an old Stack Exchange 1.0 site, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/, which you can still see in the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20100424030814/https://judaism.stackexchange.com/

It can be seen in the first [revision](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/22435/revisions):

> people for whom Jewish life and learning is a major part of their lives. (**This proposal is for migration to SE 2.0 of http://mi.yodeya.com**. Come see the great community and content we have already!)

As such, private beta was not required.

It was also said by the user who proposed the site migration [in its meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2147/2595), in response to "How come no one has the Beta badge  on "mi yodeya":

> The badge text is "Actively participated in the private beta." Mi Yodeya never had a private beta phase. There was no need, since the point of a community's private beta is " a 'probationary' basis to see if people will use it," and Mi Yodeya (actually Judaism.Stackexchange then) was founded on the pre-existing mi.yodeya community from the Stackexchange 1.0 platform. The initial user base was already there, as was a body of questions, a community culture, and provisional moderators. It would have been silly to close the site that was open to the public and open one that would be initially restricted to people who had jumped through certain hoops on Area51.

Comment: There was [no need for Mi Yodeya to have a private beta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2147/472), as the point of private beta is to establish that there's a community and a body of questions to be asked.  That already existed.  (Isaac, who provided that answer, is the site's founder.)

Comment: Thanks @Monica I've embedded it into my answer. :)

Comment: More canonical reference to the migration than the detective work in your first couple of paragraphs: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from